# iDev Custom Tab Bar Modal Window being Hidden by Tab Bar. How can I change this?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been attempting to present a modal view from one of my views that I implemented following the following iDev tutorial/source code. The custom tab bar manages view by inserting them as subviews beneath the tabBar so when I call the modal view to be displayed from the subview it is covered up at the bottom by the tab bar. I have switched the following code to above the tab bar sub view which allows the whole screen to be displayed but it still creates animation problems.

```
 // Set the view controller's frame to account for the tab bar
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-(tabBarGradient.size.height));

// Set the tag so we can find it later
viewController.view.tag = SELECTED_VIEW_CONTROLLER_TAG;

// Add the new view controller's view
[self.view insertSubview:viewController.view aboveSubview:tabBar];
```

http://idevrecipes.com/2011/01/04/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-a-custom-tab-bar/

Please help this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, i think you are presenting modal view from your subview like this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:someController animated:YES];
```

If so, your controller is presenting on current view (self) and if current view situated beneath other views - modal controller will be presented under them too.
You should get a reference to main parent view, so you could call presentModalViewController there.

In big projects with many subviews it's handy to have a reference to main view, I did it like this:

in MyAppDelegate @interface I have:

```
{
UINavigationController *navController;
}
+ (UINavigationController *) navController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navController;
```

And in the implementation:

```
// Used for showing modal windows over tabbar
static UINavigationController * _rootController = nil;

+ (UINavigationController *) navController {
    return _rootController;
}

@synthesize navController;
```

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
_rootController = navController;
```

(In this example my top view - navigation controller)

So anywhere in application I can call:

```
[[MyAppDelegate navController] presentModalViewController:someController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I've kept trying to implement this but can't seem to figure it out. Do you call @class MyAppDelegate in the headers of anywhere you want to implement it?

Comment: Anywhere I want to implement it I am adding just `#import "MyAppDelegate.h"`.